# Filter Grid record on check of checkbox

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a grid and associated checkbox with it. By default when the grid loads it dispalys all the records but i want to filter it when the checkbox is selected and load back all the records when the checkbox is unchecked. Basically i want to display only the grid data with resolved date that equals "0001-01-01".I have given the checkbox code and grid screenshot below.

```
{
    xtype: 'checkboxfield',
    boxLabel: 'Filter by UN-Resolved',
    id:'chkBox',
    handler: function() {
        var store = Ext.getCmp('defGrid').getStore();
        if(Ext.getCmp('chkBox').getValue()){
            store.filterBy([
                {filterFn: function(item) {return item.get('ID') == 'Sales';{console.log(item);}}
            ]);
            if(filter.data.items[0].data.ResolvedDate === '0001-01-01')
                {console.log("I'm inside");}
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your code **formatted** next time ! Don't rely on others to read unreadable code.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: dbrin, the question is how do i load the grid data on checking the checkbox with certain criteria (i have mentioned the criteria above the code) and once the checkbox is unchecked i want to load all the records in the grid.

Comment: you use filters, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve this... code as below ...

```
{
   xtype: 'checkboxfield',
   boxLabel: 'Filter by UN-Resolved',
   id:'chkBox',
   handler: function() {
   var grid = Ext.getCmp('defGrid');
   var checked = Ext.getCmp('chkBox').getValue();                                          

        if(checked){
            if (grid.store!=undefined) {
                    grid.store.filterBy(function(record) {
                        //console.log(record.data.ResolvedDate);
                        return record.data.ResolvedDate === '0001-01-01' ;
                        });
                    grid.getView().refresh();
            }

        }
            else{
                var grid = Ext.getCmp('defGrid');
                grid.store.clearFilter(true);
                grid.getView().refresh();
            }
    }
}
```